# about self.navigationController pushViewController (IOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios

`MoreFunctionViewController.h`  code like this:

```
      #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


      @interface MoreFunctionViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{

            UITableView *moreTable;

      }
      @property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *moreTable;


      @end
```

and `MoreFunctionViewController.m` code like this:

```
      #import "MoreFunctionViewController.h"
      #import "CustomNavigationBar.h"
      #import "MyShakeViewController.h"

      @implementation MoreFunctionViewController

      @synthesize moreTable;

      - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.title = @"More";

        CGRect tableFrame = self.view.frame;
        tableFrame.origin.y -= 20; 
        moreTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        moreTable.delegate = self;
        moreTable.dataSource = self;
        moreTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.view addSubview:moreTable];
      }

      - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
      {
             [super viewWillAppear:animated];

         [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil];
         [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twoNavbar.png"]];
     }


     ..................
     ..................

     - (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
     {
       if (indexPath.section == 0) {
          if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        NSLog(@"ddd");
        MyShakeViewController *myshakeView = [[MyShakeViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myshakeView animated:YES];
        [myshakeView release];

    }

       }

    }
```

the MyShakeViewController `-(void) viewDidLoad`  method like this:

```
   -(void) viewDidLoad{
       self.title = @"TestTitle"; 
   }
```

but cant see the Title.
if I change the

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myshakeView animated:YES];
```

To

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myshakeView animated:NO];
```

I can see the `title` , this why?

but I need the animated `YES`

How can I do it!

Comment: You are not calling the super? [super viewDidLoad] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the title from within your `MoreFunctionViewController`:

```
MyShakeViewController *myshakeView = [[MyShakeViewController alloc] init];
myShakeView.title = @"TestTitle";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myshakeView animated:YES];
[myshakeView release];
```

As for *why*, I'm not sure, I've only ever created view controllers using `initWithNibName` (so the title is loaded from the nib) and / or with custom title views in the navigation item (so I replace the title view with my own view) so I haven't used your particular setup.

Comment: OK,thinks very much ,is OK now!!